# How can the next element be scrolled by center when the current element becomes center?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

### What I want to do

[image: like this]

Like this, Initially the switching scroll.
When the current (active) element comes to the center, the next element also wants to be able to scroll in the center.

[image: this]

When it see the bottom element, the scroll stops and it changes to a switch scroll.

---

### Current status

I already have a switch scroll and a code to get the center.
[demo - JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/__R2D2/Lphwj243/10/)

For now this is not working, but I wrote the following code:

```
// Get the center of the height of .main
const rect = document.getElementsByClassName("main")[0].getBoundingClientRect();
const mainHCenter = rect.top + (rect.height / 2);
const mainWCenter = rect.left + (rect.width / 2);

// Get the element at the center of the height of .main
const centerElm = document.elementFromPoint(mainWCenter, mainHCenter);

if ($("p.active") === centerElm) {
      $(".mai").scroll().css('top',mainHCenter + 'px');
} else {
  $(".mai").scroll(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

Q. What should I do to do something like gif?

Thank you in advance.

---

### Code

```js
function onScroll() {
  $(".main > p").each(function(i) {
    $(this).removeClass('active');

    if ($(this).attr('class').includes(i) && i === swiperCnt.activeIndex) {
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }

/* from here */
// Get the center of the height of .main
    const rect = document.getElementsByClassName("main")[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    const mainHCenter = rect.top + (rect.height / 2);
    const mainWCenter = rect.left + (rect.width / 2);
    
// Get the element at the center of the height of .main
    const centerElm = document.elementFromPoint(mainWCenter, mainHCenter);
    
    if ($("p.active") === centerElm) {
          $(".mai").scroll().css('top',mainHCenter + 'px');
    } else {
      $(".mai").scroll(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
      });
    }
/* to here */

  });
}



/* swiper (doesn't matter) */
var swiperCnt = new Swiper('.swiperCnt', {
  direction: 'vertical',
  autoHeight: true,
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    type: 'bullets',
    clickable: 'true',
  },
  keyboard: {
    enabled: true,
  },
  mousewheel: {
    forceToAxis: true,
    invert: true,
  },
  renderBullet: function(index, className) {
    return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (index + 1) + '</span>';
  },
});


$(function() {
  var that;
  var i = 0;
  var j = $(".main > p").length - 1;
  $('.mai').bind('mousewheel', function(e) {
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
      //scroll down
      i++;
      if (i >= j) {
        i = j;
      }
      if (i <= j) {
        $(".main > p").each(function(i) {
          if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            if ($(this).hasClass(i)) {
              if (i < j) {
                that = $(this).next();
              } else {
                that = $(this);
              }
            }
          }
          $(this).removeClass('active');
        });
        $(that).addClass('active');
      }
    } else {
      //scroll up
      i--;
      if (i <= 0) {
        i = 0;
      }
      if (i >= 0) {
        $(".main > p").each(function(i) {
          if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            if (i > 0) {
              that = $(this).prev();
            } else {
              that = $(this);
            }
          }
          $(this).removeClass('active');
        });
        $(that).addClass('active');
      }
    }
    swiperCnt.slideTo(i);
    //prevent page from scrolling
    return false;
  });
  swiperCnt.on('scroll', function() {
    onScroll();
  });
  swiperCnt.on('paginationUpdate', function() {
    onScroll();
  });
  onScroll();
});
```

```css
/* The corresponding part is at the bottom too. (It is faster to count from the bottom)
(There is a mark in the comment) */


html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  background-color: #c6d2dd;
  color: white;
}

#wrap {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 1.8rem 4.7rem 2.7rem 2.4rem;
}

h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  display: inline;
}

.mission, .m-p, .concept, .c-p, .what, .target, .t-p, .main-p, .nb, .nb-p, .period, .p-p, .category, .cg-p, .class, .cl-p, .release, .r-p, .nbb, .per, .cat, .cla, .rel {
  display: inline-block;
}

#left, #right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

#left {
  width: 57%;
}

#right {
  position: relative;
  width: 43%;
  padding-left: 6.5rem;
}

.title {
  height: 3.55rem;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  padding-bottom: 1.7rem;
}

.solid-ti {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 0.1rem solid white;
  margin-top: 5.35rem;
}

.solid-mc {
  border-bottom: 0.1rem solid white;
  margin-left: -2.4rem;
}

.solid-tm {
  border-bottom: 0.1rem solid white;
  margin-right: -4.7rem;
}

.swiper-pagination {
  top: 6rem;
}

.max {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}

.max-inner {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.swiper-slide img {
  width: 100%;
}

.swiperP {
  height: auto;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet {
  background: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.swiper-pagination-bullet::before {
  content: "0";
  font-weight: bold;
}
.swiper-pagination-bullet:hover::before {
  content: "1";
  font-weight: bold;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  background: none;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition-duration: 0.16s;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.swiper-pagination-bullet-active::before {
  content: "1";
  font-weight: bold;
}

.mis {
  padding: 2.6rem 0 0.7rem 0;
}

.mission {
  padding-right: 2rem;
}

.con {
  padding-top: 0.7rem;
}

.concept {
  padding-right: 2rem;
}

.what {
  margin: 2rem 1.5rem 0 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.what > img {
  height: 2rem;
  margin-right: 0.3rem;
}
.what > img:last-child {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
.what span {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  border: 0.1rem solid white;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.4rem 0.4rem;
}

.tar {
  padding: 2.2rem 0 2rem 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.target {
  padding-right: 1.2rem;
}

.t-p {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.heartbox {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.heartbox div:last-child {
  user-select: none;
}

input {
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes rubberBand {
  from {
    transform: scale(1, 1, 1);
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale3d(1.15, 0.75, 1);
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale3d(0.75, 1.15, 1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 0.85, 1);
  }
  65% {
    transform: scale3d(0.95, 1.05, 1);
  }
  75% {
    transform: scale3d(1.05, 0.95, 1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
}
.heart {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: auto;
  height: 25px;
  fill: #E2E2E2;
}

#fav:checked + label .heart {
  fill: #e23b3b;
  animation: rubberBand 0.8s;
}





/*
 * from here
 */
.mai {
  margin: 2.8rem 0 0 0;
  height: 37.8rem;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
.mai::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.main p {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.main .active {
  opacity: 1;
}

/*
 * to here
 */





.▼ {
  align-self: flex-end;
  margin: 1.3rem 1.5rem 7.9625rem 0;
}

.R-under {
  text-align: right;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.nbb {
  padding-right: 4.8rem;
}

.nb {
  padding-right: 0.8rem;
}

.period {
  padding-right: 1.6rem;
}

.top {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  padding: 0.3rem 0 2rem;
  text-align: right;
}

.category {
  padding-right: 1.4rem;
}

.class {
  padding-right: 1.4rem;
}

.release {
  padding-right: 1.4rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- The corresponding part is at the bottom. (It is faster to count from the bottom)
(There is a mark in the comment) -->

<div class="solid-ti"></div>

<div id="wrap">
  <div id="left">
    <h1 class="title">動と静を共有する椅子「Rollse」</h1>

    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    <div class="swiper-container swiperCnt max">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper imgs max-inner">
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="work" src="http://placehold.jp/45/1920a6/ffffff/693x350.png?text=1" alt="Rollse-logo" /></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="work" src="http://placehold.jp/45/199fa6/ffffff/693x350.png?text=2" alt="Rollse-killer" /></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="work" src="http://placehold.jp/45/a61972/ffffff/693x350.png?text=3" alt="Rollse-data" /></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="work" src="http://placehold.jp/45/a6a619/ffffff/693x350.png?text=4" alt="Rollse-image" /></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="L-under">
      <div class="mis">
        <h3 class="mission">MISSION:</h3>
        <p class="m-p">触覚に訴えるプロダクト　　　▶︎ 3人チームの1人が、この触り心地を発見</p>
      </div>

      <div class="solid-mc"></div>

      <div class="con">
        <h2 class="concept">CONCEPT:</h2>
        <p class="c-p">緊張感のある空間をつくる。</p>
      </div>

      <div class="what">
        <img src="http://placehold.jp/45/d4d4d4/d4d4d4/28x20.png?text=_" alt="2nd" /><img src="http://placehold.jp/45/d4d4d4/d4d4d4/20x20.png?text=_" alt="ai" /><img src="http://placehold.jp/45/d4d4d4/d4d4d4/20x20.png?text=_" alt="vw" />

        <span>企画</span>
        <span>雑貨の設計</span>
        <span>ネーミング</span>
        <span>文章</span>
        <span>展開</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="right">
    <div class="top">
      <div class="cat">
        <h5 class="category">CATEGORY:</h5>
        <p class="cg-p">雑貨・プロダクト</p>
      </div>

      <div class="cla">
        <h5 class="class">CLASS:</h5>
        <p class="cl-p">デザイン研究</p>
      </div>

      <div class="rel">
        <h5 class="release">RELEASE:</h5>
        <p class="r-p">2017/06</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="heartbox">
      <div class="tar">
        <h3 class="target">TARGET:</h3>
        <p class="t-p">生活に刺激を求めている人<br> デザインされたものが好きな人
          <br> 動くのに若干抵抗がある人
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="fav" id="fav">
        <label for="fav">
            <svg class="heart" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 37 32"
              style="enable-background:new 0 0 37 32;" xml:space="preserve">
              <path class="st0" d="M27,0c-2.5,0-4.9,0.9-6.7,2.6C19.6,3.2,19,4,18.5,4.7C18,4,17.4,3.2,16.7,2.6C14.9,0.9,12.5,0,10,0
            C4.5,0,0,4.5,0,10c0,3.7,1.2,6.7,3.9,9.8c3.9,4.6,13.9,11.6,14.3,11.9c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1s0.2,0,0.3-0.1
            c0.4-0.3,10.4-7.3,14.3-11.9c2.7-3.2,3.9-6.1,3.9-9.8C37,4.5,32.5,0,27,0z" /></svg>
          </label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="solid-tm"></div>





    <!--
from here
-->
    <div class="mai max">
      <section class="main max-inner">
        <p class="active 0">This part is Switch scroll. (move by scrolling) <br> rolls（渦）×rose（バラ）<br> モチーフの見た目から命名しました。
          <br> “R”は小文字より大文字にすることで、凛々しさを演出し、
          <br> 大人の美しさを際立たせました。
        </p>
        <br>
        <p class="1">触覚に訴える。それで日常の問題を解決できたら。ついつい無駄に過ごしてしまいがちな日常。<br> そこであえて触感の悪いものを提供して、その無駄な時間を少しでも減らせる手助けになる商品をつくりました。
        </p>
        <br>
        <p class="2">無数の紙を渦状に丸めた形状によって、片面は固く、もう片面は程よく弾力のある、画期的な椅子になっています。<br> 様々な素材や大きさのロールによるカスタム仕様なので、様々な展開が可能です。
        </p>
        <p class="3">毎日の慣れた生活空間の中に新感覚の刺激を与えてくれ、エキサイティングな感覚と少しのスリルを味わうことができます。</p>
      </section>
    </div>
    <!-- 
to here
-->





    <img src="http://placehold.jp/45/d4d4d4/d4d4d4/14x12.png?text=_" alt="▼" class="▼" width="14" />

    <div class="R-under">
      <div class="nbb">
        <h4 class="nb">N.B.:</h4>
        <p class="nb-p">投票第１位</p>
      </div>

      <div class="per">
        <h4 class="period">PERIOD:</h4>
        <p class="p-p">1週間</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Could you explain more what will happen when scrolled to the end? I'm not sure what is a switch scroll.

Comment: @Jacob I'm sorry for the mistake in selecting my words.
The first and the last are movements such as elements that switch as it scroll, like the current JSFiddle demo. (It looks like the original scroll: the movement of characters moving from top to bottom will stop)
While the current element is at the center (= until the last element is visible), the current element is scrolled while being fixed at the center like gif. (This scroll is a movement like moving letters from top to bottom as usual. In terms of CSS, like `fixed`)

Comment: After experiments,  https://codepen.io/jacobsun/pen/VNywYd, I wonder did you mean an asynchronous multi-scrolling effects? When an item scroll to the vertical center of the container, the sibling items would be kicked to scroll too? If so, I believe the easing function is the best solution to the sibling item.

Comment: @Jacob Thank you very much. Certainly scrolling while being fixed at the center!
But I want my brother element not to be kicked out of the screen. And when I convert "Switch to highlight" scroll to "fixed at center" scroll, I feel a little harder, so if you don't mind, can you fork my code?
I also created a [Codepen ver.](https://codepen.io/__R2D2/pen/OGzPmW) (The code is exactly the same as the JSFiddle ver.)  And I created a gif that might be a bit more easy to understand. [here](https://i.imgur.com/rdZcBXz.gifv)
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updated.

You can find the js file in https://gist.github.com/jacobsun/1e2eff94b082ed446c730027c241fe03

HTML structure like this:

```
    <div class="lazy-scroll-wrapper">
        <div class="lazy-scroll-itemlist">
            <div class="lazy-scroll-item a">A</div>
            <div class="lazy-scroll-item b">B</div>
            <div class="lazy-scroll-item c">C</div>
            <div class="lazy-scroll-item d">D</div>
            <div class="lazy-scroll-item e">E</div>
            <div class="lazy-scroll-item f">F</div>
            <div class="lazy-scroll-item g">G</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

After you load the script, run

```
 lazyScroll({
    height: '400px', // required, wrapper height
    itemHeight: '50px', // required, item height

    wrapper: '.lazy-scroll-wrapper', // optional, selector
    itemlist: '.lazy-scroll-itemlist', // optional, selector
    item: '.lazy-scroll-item', // optional, selector
    // optional, default: 0, allow up and down,
    // 1: no scroll down, -1: no scroll up
    noDirection: 0,
    highlightClass: 'highlight', // optional, current highlght class, no dot
    step: 3 // optional, control scroll speed
  })
```

The main downside of the script is you have to code the element appearance manually, I mean the width, height, margin... I can't find an easy way to figure that out with script. e.g. How many elements are visible, in an simple scroll effect, this is not a problem. But in our effect, we have to know when we don't need to scroll. There would be a lot of complicate computing if we let the script handle the properties.

Demo: https://codepen.io/jacobsun/full/wZydXX

I use mousewheel, which is a deprecated event, I found it is a reliable and easy one, if you have better solution, please comment.

Comment: Woow! Thank you so so much!!
I'll try with my code after the night is over :D

Comment: You kindly make a script!
I was trying to test it with my code, but I had been struggling.. lol
I appreciate it very much!! xD